# 'Could not find a valid Azure DevOps team project for the selected account' Azure Synapse Git config

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-synapse, azure-git-deployment

I am trying to configure an Azure DevOps Git repository in Azure Synapse. After selecting the organization name, the portal displays the message: 'Could not find a valid Azure DevOps team project for the selected account.'.
[image]

The account I use to configure Git in Synapse is part of a DevOps Security Group with the following permissions:
[image]

The DevOps organization is already connected to the Azure AD tenant:
[image]

Does anyone knows what configuration I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your Azure AD tenant connected to the Azure DevOps organization. By default Azure DevOps organization is connected to the Microsoft Directory, Make sure you change your Azure DevOps org from Microsoft to your Azure AD Default directory connected to your Azure subscription.

I tried to connect my Azure DevOps git repository to my synapse resource like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

**I went to my Azure DevOps account, switched the directory from Microsoft to Default Directory, created a new Azure DevOps project, and imported one GitHub repository.**

[image]

[image]

Azure AD Default directory connected to Azure DevOps successfully like below:-

[image]

Connecting Azure DevOps git repo with Azure Synapse:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Azure DevOps git repo connected successfully like below:-

[image]

Comment: In the organization settings in Azure DevOps, I see that the DevOps organization is already connected to the Azure AD tenant.

Comment: Is it connected to the same AD Tenant as your Synapse?

Comment: Yes it is, I adjusted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to connect a repository to an Azure Data Factory. I could fix this problem by changing my user type from Guest to Member in Microsoft Entra ID (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops#how-can-i-convert-an-azure-ad-guest-into-a-member).